# How to validate the user input in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm searching for the possibility to check the user input in the view. 
And trigger a **flash[:error]** if these are incorrect.

Similar to the picture which I attached:

[image]

How can I do that in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html which describes all sorts of validation and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html describes how you can show this using flash[:error] in UI

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).

It has [an interesting session on validation](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-user_validations) that shows the different kinds of validation and likely will fullfil all your needs.